# Mi registro no se actualiza con ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Desde hace días estoy intentando hacer un `update` pero nada que me actualiza el registro que quiero.

Ya he intentado de dos formas y ninguna me ha resultado. No se si tengo un error de sintaxis o cual puede ser el problema.

Este es el código:

```
// UPDATE CLIENT
protected void updatecliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaconexion1"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "update cliente set cedula = @cedula, nombre = @nombre, telefono = @telefono, direccion = @direccion where cedula = @cedulaWhere and nombre = @nombreWhere and telefono = @telefonoWhere and direccion = @direccionWhere";
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conexion;




        //Vamos a agregar los valores como parámetros para evitar la concatenación en la consulta.
        //Valores con los que se van a actualizar los campos
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedula", ccliente.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", ncliente.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", ctelefono.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", cdireccion.Text);
        //Valores para las condiciones.
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedulaWhere", "'123456789'");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreWhere", "'Luis Ocampo'");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefonoWhere", "'3116085275'");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccionWhere", "'sddferr'");

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // aquí puedes manejar las excepciones
    }
}
```

Y aca el codigo de como empece a hacerlo:

```
string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaconexion1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
            conexion.Open();
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("update cliente set " + 
                                 "cedula = '" + ccliente.Text + "', nombre = '" +
                                 ncliente.Text + "', telefono = '" + ctelefono.Text +
                                 "', direccion = '" + cdireccion.Text + "' where cedula = '" + 
                                 ccliente.Text + "' and nombre = '" +
                                 ncliente.Text + "' and telefono = '" + 
                                 ctelefono.Text + "' and direccion = '" + 
                                 cdireccion.Text + "'", conexion);

            ccliente.Text = string.Empty;
            ncliente.Text = string.Empty;
            ctelefono.Text = string.Empty;
            cdireccion.Text = string.Empty;

            msgerror.Text = "Información actualizada con exito";

            conexion.Close();
```

[image: tabla cliente]

Comment: Te falta una coma despues de `nombre = @nombre`

Comment: yo me estaba guiando de como es la consulta el SQL server y la estoy haciendo asi

update cliente set telefono = '864346', cedula = '8826537',
nombre = 'Lucho', direccion = 'Cll 60 # 15 - 45'
where cedula = '123456789' 
and nombre = 'Luis Ocampo'
and telefono = '3116085275'
and direccion = 'sddferr';

Comment: Pero asi me parece que es cambiar todos los campos pero solo necesito cambiar algunos, estoy probando con solo nombre y no me hace el update

Comment: Te marca algun error? o simplemente no lo hace?

Comment: No, no lo hace.

Comment: Tal vez sea por las comillas que le estas agregando a las variables "Where" por ejemplo: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedulaWhere", "'123456789'"); deberia ir así: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedulaWhere", "123456789");

Comment: sigue igual, no hace la actualizacion.

Comment: No es un poco excesivo el where? Deberias hacerlo por la clave primaria o en este caso el documento "cedula"

Comment: Podrías agregar la estructura de tu tabla a la que le estas haciendo el update?

Comment: Concuerdo con @GonzaloPigni, lo recomendable es hacerlo a través de la llave primaria.

Comment: Tambien en el primer codigo, falta abrir la conexion con conexion.Open(). Además recomiendo declarar "conexion" antes del Try, y agregar un Finally para cerrar la misma con conexion.Close()

Comment: T-T ... no me guarda, gracias Gonzalo, no entiendo bien esa parte de hacerlo a trave de la PK.

Comment: Se refiere a que si vas a hacer un update, en lugar de poner miles de opciones en tu where, pongas solo el where basándote en un solo dato único, que viene siendo la llave primaria.

Comment: lo primero que recomendaria es que quites el try..catch del updatecliente_Click, sino vas hacer nada con el control de errores es para problemas, quizas tengas un error en el update y ni te enteras, sino muestra el mensaje de error que pudiera generarse

Comment: no necesitas un where tan complejo, no tienes un identificador unico del registro? por ejemplo la cedula de la persona no lo identifica como unico, porque si es asi solo usa este en el where y no todos los campos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que pueden haber 2 problemas, el primero es que el `WHERE` debe hacerse por una clave primaria y no por todos los datos de la tabla, en tu caso tienes los valores hardcoded y en la captura de la tabla, no aparecen registros con esos valores, entonces nunca encuentra que fila actualizar.

Prueba de la siguiente manera: (fijate que cambié el where a solo la Cedula)

```
// UPDATE CLIENT
        protected void updatecliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //para probar, pero en realidad se deberia tomar de una consulta anterior a seleccionar el usuario para actualizar
            string cedula = "0000";

            string query = "update cliente set cedula = @cedula, nombre = @nombre, telefono = @telefono, direccion = @direccion where cedula = @cedulaWhere";

            string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaconexion1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
            try
            {                
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conexion;

                //Vamos a agregar los valores como parámetros para evitar la concatenación en la consulta.
                //Valores con los que se van a actualizar los campos
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedula", ccliente.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", ncliente.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", ctelefono.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", cdireccion.Text);
                //Valores para las condiciones.
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedulaWhere", cedula);

                conexion.Open();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // aquí puedes manejar las excepciones
            }
            finally
            {
                conexion.Close();
            }
        }
```

Saludos!

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedulaWhere", cedula); al colocarlo asi me muestra un error, me dice que el no existe en el contexto actual.

Comment: @EdwardSc me faltó la linea de la conecctionString, ahi la agregue, prueba nuevamente, saludos!